# How to Pass onNewIntent value to Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, bundle, onnewintent

I want to pass intent value to fragment, right now in the activity i am getting the intent value through onNewIntent but i am passing the intent value through Bundle to Fragment but it's not working.

```
* MainActivity.java *

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    parseMessage = intent.getStringExtra("message");

    if (parseMessage.length()>0) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("parseJson", parseMessage);

        AbcdFragment activityFrag = new AbcdFragment();
        activityFrag.setArguments(bundle);
    }  
}

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") 
public class AllPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public AllPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch(position){
            case 0:
                return AbcdFragment.newInstance(getApplicationContext());
            case 1:
                return HelloFragment.newInstance(getApplicationContext());
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT[position].toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}

* AbcdFragment.java *

public class AbcdFragment extends Fragment{

    public static AbcdFragment newInstance(Context context) {
       AbcdFragment fragment = new AbcdFragment();
       fragment.context = context;

       return fragment;
    }

   @SuppressLint("InflateParams") 
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.abcd_activity,container,false);

    try {
        parseJsonRes = getArguments().getString("parseJson");
        Log.d("ParseActivityMsg", parseJsonRes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return view;
  }
}
```

It's a viewpager fragment i want pass the intent value to AbcdFragment but i am getting null value in AbcdFragment.

Please kindly go through my code and suggest me some solution

Comment: Can you paste the AbcdFragment code as well ? especially the methods in your read from the bundle ?

Comment: ya i have updated my Code please kindly go through my post

Comment: Can you move the following code to onCreate() method instead of from onCreateView() : parseJsonRes = getArguments().getString("parseJson");

Comment: you are saying in fragment.

Comment: Yes in the AbcdFragment itself

Comment: yes i move the code parseJsonRes = getArguments().getString("parseJson"); to onCreate method but it's not working.

Comment: Can you pass a hard coded string in parseMessage? Just to make sure intent.getStringExtra("message") not giving null values.

Comment: ya i have hard coded the value but still the same result..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at how you are creating fragment in the view pager `return AbcdFragment.newInstance(getApplicationContext());`

and then look at your implementation of `AbcdFragment.newInstance`

```
public static AbcdFragment newInstance(Context context) {
   AbcdFragment fragment = new AbcdFragment();
   fragment.context = context;

   return fragment;
}
```

In `return AbcdFragment.newInstance()` you have to set the arguments for the fragment that you create inside that method. Also, you aren't even using the fragment you created in onNewIntent, you are just creating it and doing nothing with it.

Also, chances are if onNewIntent is being called, MainActivity could already active so AbcdFragment would probably already be in memory, therefore getItem wouldn't be called and a newInstance wouldn't be created with the new arguments, if that makes sense. Because you only have 2 fragments in your ViewPager, once they are created for the first time they will be stored in memory instead of being recreated each time you swap between the two.

So, if you want to persist with your current implementation, you have to set the arguments in `AbcdFragment.newInstance` and ensure that a new instance of the fragment is created AFTER onNewIntent. This probably isn't the best way to get data to your fragment.